# c# Unity Mathf.PingPong not working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My value stays the same rather than being pingponged

```
IEnumerator CrossHairScale(){
    float size = 0;
    float finalsize = Mathf.Lerp (minSize, maxSize, Mathf.PingPong(size, 1));

    while (transform != null) {
        transform.localScale = new Vector3 (finalsize, finalsize, finalsize);
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are `minSize` and `maxSize` assigned?

Comment: at the top of my class

Comment: Please post the relevant parts of the class.

Comment: what are u trying to achieve? the code seems ok and localscale should stay the same

Comment: i am trying to make the local scale up and down with the ping pong but as the value being ping pinged doesn't change neither does my local scale

Comment: basically i just want to make the game object this script is attached to constantly scale up and down

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have misunderstood the usage of [`Mathf.PingPong(float t, float length)`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.PingPong.html). It accepts two arguments: `t` is the value to be limited, `length` is the maximum value that can be returned. When `t` is outside the range of [0, `length`], that's when the ping-pong effect occurs.

**Here's what's going on**

In your code, the only `t` value you ever pass into `Mathf.PingPong()` is an unchanging value of 0, given by

```
float size = 0;
```

That means, the next line of code is basically

```
float finalsize = Mathf.Lerp (minSize, maxSize, Mathf.PingPong(0, 1));
```

And `Mathf.PingPong(0, 1) = 0`, so all your code is really doing is

```
float finalsize = Mathf.Lerp (minSize, maxSize, 0);
```

Ultimately, you're always going to get back

```
float finalsize = minSize;
```

**So, how do you fix this?**

What you need to be doing is incrementing the `t` value (in this case, `size`) you pass into `Mathf.PingPong()` - otherwise, it's always going to evaluate to the same value each time, and the value you assign to `localScale` won't change. Consider trying this code instead:

```
IEnumerator CrossHairScale(){
    float size = 0;

    while (transform != null) {
        // Here, we change size according to the time since the last frame
        size += Time.deltaTime;

        // Now, Mathf.PingPong() will return a value bouncing between 0 and 1
        float finalsize = Mathf.Lerp (minSize, maxSize, Mathf.PingPong(size, 1));

        transform.localScale = new Vector3 (finalsize, finalsize, finalsize);
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Glad I could help out - let me know if you run into any problems with the implementation I suggested.

Comment: one more thing, would a more elegant way of doing it be:

Comment: void Update () {
  transform.localScale = new Vector3(Mathf.PingPong(Time.time, 1), Mathf.PingPong(Time.time, 1), Mathf.PingPong(Time.time, 1));
 }

Comment: Depends on your needs - if you just need an object to get bigger and smaller and don't need to do anything else with it, using `Time.time` is perfectly fine. Using a coroutine gives you more control, in that you can pause/restart the scaling from a certain point, and can have multiple objects that are offset in their scaling (which can lead to some interesting effects).

Answer (score 0):

This will run in Z axis only between [0, Endpos]:

```
var position = new vector3(0, 0, Mathf.PingPong((SpeedValue * Time.time), EndPos));
```

But if you want custom minimum value like 5, -3, etc.
If you want negative number then minus that number do something like this:

```
var position = new vector3(0, 0, Mathf.PingPong((SpeedValue * Time.time), (EndPos + MinValue)) - MinValue);
```

If you want positive number then plus that number do something like this:

```
var position = new vector3(0, 0, Mathf.PingPong((SpeedValue * Time.time), (EndPos - MinValue)) + MinValue);
```