# What does Unity's Mathf.PingPong actually do?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The Unity Docs for [Mathf.PingPong](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.PingPong.html) says:

> PingPongs the value `t`, so that it is never larger than `length` and never smaller than `0`.

I get that it's rotating a value between 0 and `length`, what I don't get is what is the value `t` doing and how does it relate to how PingPong works?

If I set `t` to any constant, I always get that value back

```
void Update()
{
// always prints: 1
    print(Mathf.PingPong(1f, 1f));

// always prints 0
    print(Mathf.PingPong(0f, 1f));
}
```

Every time I see PingPong used in examples it has `Time.time` used for the `t` value (or some maths based on `Time.time`). Why?

The only explanation I've seen was from this question: [c# Unity Mathf.PingPong not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40554432/c-sharp-unity-mathf-pingpong-not-working) which implies that the value of `t` must always be changing, but again it's not clear why or what's going on.

So, what is `Mathf.PingPong` actually doing with `t` /  what is the value `t` actually for, and how do you use the function properly?

Comment: FYI: You can look up the source code: https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/blob/02d565cf3dd0f6b15069ba976064c75dc2705b08/Runtime/Export/Math/Mathf.cs#L360

Answer (score 16, accepted):

So `Mathf.PingPong()` uses a function calls `Mathf.Repeat()`

These are likely intended as tweening/easing helper functions

So `Mathf.Repeat(float t, float length)` will create a graph like this
[image]
Where `length` is the length of each line segment, and `t` is the X value of the function (the return value being the corresponding Y position on the graph)

What `Mathf.PingPong(float t, float length)` does looks more like this
[image]
Again where `length` describes the height of each triangle and `t` gives the X position

A common use case for this is we want some value to change *along with* this graph, as in walking along it with a steadily increasing X value, and take the value of Y at each step.
The easiest way to do this is to pass `Time.time` in as the `t` argument, which will get the value of this function at the corresponding X position.

```
float Y = Mathf.PingPong(Time.time,Max_Y_Value);
```