# Mathf.PingPong from 1 to 0

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, lerp, math-functions

I have created a helper to PingPong from 1 to 0, but I'm having a hard time inverting this, so that the value goes from 1 to 0.

Below you can see the code, I'm currently using. I'm also not sure if this is even possible.

```
_lerpPulse = PingPong(Time.time * 0.5f, 0f, 1f);
```

And the helper

```
float PingPong(float aValue, float aMin, float aMax)
{
    return Mathf.PingPong(aValue, aMax - aMin) + aMin;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: why dont you just use the sin / cos function? by the way, the `+ aMin` is notnecessary

Comment: I was using Sin initially, but couldnt find out how to go from 1 to 0 _lerpPulse = (Mathf.Sin(Time.time * 2f) + 1f) / 2f This is what is was using and works for 0 to 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Mathf.PingPong` creates a graph like this
[image]
So, to begin at a peak, you can add the distance to the peak along the x axis to the time parameter, which will be sqrt(2)/2 * the length, or 0.707 * length

```
float PingPong1To0(float aValue, float aMin, float aMax)
{
    float offset 0.707f *  (aMax - aMin); // sqrt(2)/2
    return Mathf.PingPong(aValue +offset, aMax - aMin) + aMin;
}
```

Should hit the falling side of that triangle

Comment: answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61307619/7711148) better explaining how `mathf.PingPong` works

Comment: This is indeed what I was looking for! The only thing I'm wondering though, is how can I change the speed of the PingPong? Initially I used Time.time * 0.5f, but this isn't working with the offset for some reason.

Comment: `Mathf.PingPong((Time.time * 0.5f) + offset, aMax...`? didn't work?