# How do I make this object move back and forth in an arc?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Right now the enemy moves in the +x and +y directions. Then when it reaches the "range" value it goes in the -x and -y directions. I want to modify this so after it reaches the range on the y axis, it travels in the +x and -y directions. Then when y = the starting position (ie back on the ground). It travels back to the starting position in the same arc.

Then it would just keep traveling back and forth in a arc.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Enemy: Enemy_Damage
{
    [SerializeField] private float range;     // The range of movement for the object
    [SerializeField] private float speed;     // The speed at which the object moves

    private Vector3 startPosition;
    private float Xdirection = 1f; // 1 for moving right, -1 for moving left
    private float Ydirection = 1f;

    private void Start()
    {
        startPosition = transform.position;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (CompareTag("Ground"))
        {
            Ydirection *= -1f;
        }
        // Calculate the new position based on the direction and speed
        float newPosition = Mathf.PingPong(Time.time * speed, range);
        Vector3 targetPosition = startPosition + new Vector3(1 * newPosition * Xdirection, Ydirection * newPosition, 0);

        // Move the object
        transform.position = targetPosition;
    }
}
```

Tried making conditions to check when y == range. But none of them worked

Comment: Just a note, are you sure your `Enemy` is a kind of "damage"

Answer (score 0):

`Math.PingPong()` is simply going up from zero to your `range` value and back down again. You are adding this value onto both your `x` and `y`. You only want to ping-pong the y value, so only add it to the y value.

```cs
var offset = Time.time * speed;
float newPosition = Mathf.PingPong(offset , range);
Vector3 targetPosition = startPosition + new Vector3(1 * Xdirection * offset , Ydirection * newPosition, 0);
```

Notice how `offset` will increase steadily, but `newPosition` (which i recommend re-naming, it's not a position it's an offset value) will ping-pong.

To go back again just subtract these values instead of adding them.

[Check out this answer for a more detailed explination of Mathf.PingPong()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61307619/7711148).

Comment: I want it to go back and forth in an arc. This code just increases the height and then travels back and forth.

Comment: Apologies, there was a copy-error in my script. It's been fixed.

Comment: Almost. But how do I make it go the other way once x == 0?

Comment: once `x` is the value at `range`, make `Xdirection` negative. Once `x` is back at `0`, make it positive again. Same for `Ydirection`

Comment: `      if (Mathf.Abs(transform.position.y - startPosition.y) < threshold)
        {
            Xdirection *= -1f;
            Ydirection *= -1f;
        }` This makes my character disappear.

Comment: @BNK that's not what I told you to do

Comment: Well what I do I need to change? I don't understand.